# Questions asked by users with less than 100 rep should go to a special review queue

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, question-quality, proposed-changes

I love SO and all the child forums that exist today. I remember landing here occasionally though I wasn't a developer, but a tester, and my first impression of the site and that remained for about two years now was that there were only geniuses here and it would be hard to find something useful to me. People with no less than a Masters degree on some software specialty or major.

The industry is diverse, though, and there is a mixture between very naive, egocentric and lazy people who seem to join the site in an exponential manner.  There are also people who are really interested in software development, but don't seem to have the same required talent as people who make really high quality questions here.

My proposal is that every question made by people who doesn't have a minimal reputation of, probably 100 but **specifically related to the question's main tag**, should go under review by people who has **at least 100 or 200 reputation specifically related to the question's main tag**. Something like this is or was already implemented possibly in the past and the results might have turned out not too good, but this might be the right time.

I'd love to make this suggestion more feature rich with statistics and queries and everything, but it would take me several days or weeks to do that due to my daily duties, and this has been going on and I want to do something about it.

**EDIT**

I think my intention was not originally understood. I think the Triage review queue can be improved, though *SOME* new questions from newcommers are not that bad quality (I'm very much OK with that, I didn't mean that only PhD level questions must stay) but probably a main tag should exist and only high-rep'd people on that very specific tag should have a final approve for them.

@Makoto: you knida shred away all the passionate side of my question which I wanted to express, but I guess it's OK to leave feelings out.

Comment: It already works that way.  The Triage review queue reviews between 4000 and 5000 questions every day.  Massive amount of work with very little to show for it, SE ignores the review recommendations and only uses it to power their [newnav] questions view.

Comment: they tried that already: for questions it didn't work. See [How can we make First Posts review actually useful?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234153/165773) "I'm about fed up with the First Posts review queue.

Oh, it was a nice enough idea in theory..."

Comment: Interesting... one says it used to work that way, and another that it currently does. But the review queue is for questions previously flagged, isn't it?

Comment: the way you suggest it here - reviewing _every_ question and doing "just something / anything" - is one that was tried and failed. The way that works now (and works reasonably well) is bit different: system automatically picks _some_ questions that are likely of low quality and reviewers get much more concrete job to decide between whether to remove these from site or let them stay

Comment: ...they say that this new way (which replaced old, failed one) handles about 20% of questions posted to Stack Overflow

Comment: *SE ignores the review recommendations* - @HansPassant Are you saying Triage reviewed questions still end up on the site no matter what or that they can end up on the site if no one acts of the flags cast on them?

Answer (score 11):

If you are suggesting that a new / low rep user's post should first be reviewed by others (possibly 3 - 5?) in the community before they can be seen / answered, it is a very bad idea.

1. Not all new / low rep users post bad content.
2. Having another queue would put additional burden on people between 100-200 rep.
3. Your assumption that people between rep 100-200 are smarter and understand the system better than new users isn't completely valid.
4. Your assumption that people between rep 100-200 would be willing to review this isn't valid either (*no complaints, it's not their job*).
5. This could potentially lead to more help vampires because new users might want to answer *anything and everything* which could get them to 100+ rep (giving them the ability to post "directly"). Which could lead to sock puppets as well. More sock puppets ⇒ more work for mods. Not to mention more accounts created to circumvent question bans, answer bans, etc.
6. If a new user's post has to wait for some time before it can be answered / seen, then there is a good probability that that user might leave SO and never come back.

Comment: Nice answer, but I think at least point 4 doesn't take into account Makoto's hacksaw results.

Comment: @Gimby:  I didn't recall seeing anything about "willingness" to review in the original post...if I had I wouldn't have hacked it out.

Comment: @Makoto Fair enough, with or without hacksaw I don't really see anything in the current state of the question which matches point 4. There are no assumptions being made about what people between 100 and 200 rep are willing to do, its just a minimum rep requirement being defined.

Comment: @TheLostMind I am not assuming that people with X rep is smarter or dumber. I'm saying that for you to get some kind of rep level, you need to make sure your questions and answers are good enough. Probably very few people is willing to review and it's understandable. Some new questions make me want to puck my eyes out and throw them at the screen, but I am, and I think we need a somewhat tougher policy

Comment: @Chisko - There is a tougher policy  - *Qbans and answer bans*. A lot of people get rate limited. Lot of things to ensure that users (especially new users) don't post garbage

Comment: @TheLostMind you got me very wrong mate. Please check my last edit